# Google analytics event on button click not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

I have a contact form whose id is `#mailButton`. I've set up Google Analytics for the site (which works just fine). The site is much bigger than this (and runs on WordPress) but a truncated version is:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" class="button" id="mailButton">SUBMIT</input>
</form>

<script>
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']); // Edited out my account number
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
<script>
    $('#mailButton').click(function() {
        console.log("Button Clicked!");
      _gaq.push('_trackEvent', 'Contact', 'New Enquiry');
    });
</script>
```

When I click the button, console correctly logs `Button Clicked!`. However, Google Analytics shows no event when I go to `Behaviour -> Events -> Overview`. I've clicked it many, many times, it only shows once click event from a few weeks ago (when I didn't click it but a customer might have). What am I missing here?

*For further clarification, this contact form is being generated by Wordpress' "Contact Form 7", if that makes any difference here*

Live site is here: http://agoodman.com.au/ and the contact form in question is the one right next to the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a small mistake, you have missed “[ ]“ . Correct it, Should work

**New Code**

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact', 'New Enquiry']);

Comment: Good spot, although I've changed it and events aren't showing up. Unless there is some lag between the event and Analytics reporting it? (it's set to show today's events).

Comment: Update: Just took a look and there was indeed a lag in reporting, works fine now! Cheers.